# Phonegap : Sqlite -> export data off the phone

Tags: cordova, export

What are the options for extracting or exporting data from a sqlite backed Phonegap application?

I'd like the user to be able to "export" a json or xml representation of their data, not sure what the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd want to go through the following steps:

1. Create a FileWriter
2. Query your DB
3. Loop through the results writing each line to the FileWriter in the format of your choice.
4. Call the FileTransfer.upload() method to send your file to a server.

Alternatively you could:

1. Query your DB
2. Loop through the results building an JSON object of XML doc.
3. Use XHR to post the data to a server.

Comment: I went with simply emailing the data.